# Application Specific User Role Configuration - OpenID

Tags: .net, authorization, openid-connect

Currently, we have 4 .NET applications which all having form based authentication. All these applications have their specific roles for users.
For example, consider applications are A, B, C, and D and each application has one user. A has user A1, B has user B1, C has user C1, D has user D1.

A1 has role of ARole1,ARole2 in application A.
B1 has role of BRole1 in application B.
C1 has role of CRole1,CRole2 in application C.
D1 has role of DRole1 in application D.

Currently these roles are mapped against users in application specific sql DB. Once users log in to the application these roles are fetched from DB.

Now we are moving all these applications to SAPCDC for authentication using OpenID connect and will be common login for all these four applications.
I am okay with the authentication part in SAPCDC.

But not sure how to manage/migrate these existing application-specific roles of the users.

Do we need to map these roles as OpenID scopes against the user ?

Or we can keep the application specific roles in the current sql DB against user? Once the user is authenticated through OpenID we can check the roles from the DB ?

Any guidance on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After authentication and before token issuance, it is common for the OIDC provider to look up domain specific claims (such as roles) and then include them in tokens as `claims`. This is typically done via a REST or database connection.

Typically the OIDC provider has its own user fields, eg:

- User name
- Email
- Generated subject claim (often a GUID)

In some cases roles can be included in the OIDC data, but it is common to keep them separate. Some domain specific claims - such as a `customer subscription level` - are best stored outside the OIDC data.

You need to design a way to map from the OIDC data to your domain specific data. A couple of common techniques are:

- A DB query that filters on email
- Adding the subject claim to your DB data

Here is a [Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) that discusses design patterns around customizing claims, which is an important area so that your APIs are able to authorize correctly.